# passenger-install-apache2-module is not working in ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I'm trying to execute `passenger-install-apache2-module` but it is not working.

My Command Results:

```
$ passenger-install-apache2-module
Welcome to the Phusion Passenger Apache 2 module installer, v4.0.24.

This installer will guide you through the entire installation process. It
shouldn't take more than 3 minutes in total.

Here's what you can expect from the installation process:

 1. The Apache 2 module will be installed for you.
 2. You'll learn how to configure Apache.
 3. You'll learn how to deploy a Ruby on Rails application.

Don't worry if anything goes wrong. This installer will advise you on how to
solve any problems.

Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.


--------------------------------------------

Checking for required software...

 * Checking for C compiler...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/gcc
 * Checking for C++ compiler...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/g++
 * Checking for Curl development headers with SSL support...
      Found: no
      Error: Cannot find the `curl-config` command.
 * Checking for OpenSSL development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h
 * Checking for Zlib development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/include/zlib.h
 * Checking for Ruby development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /home/hemant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h
 * Checking for OpenSSL support for Ruby...
      Found: yes
 * Checking for RubyGems...
      Found: yes
 * Checking for Rake (associated with /home/hemant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby)...
      Found: yes
      Location: /home/hemant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby /home/hemant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/rake
 * Checking for rack...
      Found: yes
 * Checking for Apache 2...
      Found: no
 * Checking for Apache 2 development headers...
      Found: no
 * Checking for Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers...
      Found: no
 * Checking for Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers...
      Found: no

Some required software is not installed.
But don't worry, this installer will tell you how to install them.
Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.

--------------------------------------------

Installation instructions for required software

 * To install Curl development headers with SSL support:
   Please run apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev or libcurl4-gnutls-dev, whichever you prefer.

 * To install Apache 2:
   Please install it with apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker

 * To install Apache 2 development headers:
   Please install it with apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev

 * To install Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers:
   Please install it with apt-get install libapr1-dev

 * To install Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers:
   Please install it with apt-get install libaprutil1-dev

If the aforementioned instructions didn't solve your problem, then please take
a look at the Users Guide:

  /home/hemant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.24/doc/Users guide Apache.html
  http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html
```

And I tried to run `apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
[sudo] password for hemant: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.1) but 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
                        Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here's my system versions.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]
$ gem -v
2.1.11
rvm -v

rvm 1.23.16 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.1.rc4
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.3.5
```

Can anyone please help me on this matter? :(

Plus I'm having this problem! :(

```
$ require_relative '../spec_helper'
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'

require_relative: command not found
```

Comment: This really looks like it'd be answered better on http://superuser.com as it appears to be apt-get repo related. It's not RVM or Passenger related as it's tied to prerequisites needed to install Apache, not Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, it seems that Apache2 is not installed.

`* Checking for Apache 2...
      Found: no`

If it is, could you provide its version ?